# Is "Determinant" a Hochschild coboundary?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, cohomology, determinants, hochschild-cohomology

Assume that $n>2$.
Is there an  associative unital  algebra structure on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that $D$, the determinant as a  $n-\text{form} $ on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$,
would be  a  Hochschild coboundary?

What is  an explicit formula for a  $(n-1)$-  linear  map $\beta:\overbrace{\mathbb{C}^{n}\times \ldots \mathbb{C}^{n}}^{ (n-1)\;\; times} \to \mathbb{C} $  with  $\delta \beta =D$?

What about if we drop the associativity from the defenition of an algebra. In this case the "Determinant" is Hocshield coboundary with the  non assiciative multiplication $(a,b)×(c,d)=(ad, bc)$.(This multiplication in dimension $2$ satisfies $xy=\tau(yx)$ for the involutin automorphism $\tau(x,y)=(y,x)$).

> Is it true to say that for every dimension, the Determinat a Hocshield coboundary, in this non associative manner?

Comment: Presumably you mean "an algebra structure on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and an augmentation $\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}$ for which the determinant is a coboundary in the complex with coefficients in the augmentation bimodule"? Usually, when mentioning Hochschild complex of an algebra $A$ without clearly stating coefficients, people mean coefficients in $A$, but it does not seem to be the case for you.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko  The  bimodule  is $A^{*}$ so  a every  $n$ linear  map  $f: A^n \to  A^{*}$  is identified by a  $n+1$ linear  map $g:A^{n+1} \to \mathbb{C}$. Now  is  my  question obvious?

Comment: Here  A is  $\mathbb{C}^n$.